TailwindCSS Colors not working when taking text (Code) from database
I got a Laravel project, with TailwindCSS and I am trying to retrieve a piece of text from my database: "<div class="bg-red-500 text-green-200 text-lg border">Code should be here</div>".
And I use Laravel Facade to retrieve it and got this in my view {!! $code !!}.
Now the issue is, the border seems to be applied, the larger text seems to work well, its just I cant set a background or text color, it just doesn't work.
What I am aiming to do, is that I can have a piece of frontend code including TailwindCSS stored in my database, and that I can basically 'pull' and store different code snippets to my database. (And also show the code working on my website)
What i already tried:
I already tried setting custom colors in my TailwindCSS config, but that did not fix the issue.
And I dont seem to be able to find a anwser on the internet either.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Tailwind's JIT only adds the styles that it sees in your blade files.
If either of the styles bg-red-500 text-green-200 text-lg border is not present anywhere else, then they won't be available since Tailwind cannot infer that you need them simply by looking at the string {!! $code !!}.

To add to this, one could consider using the safelist configuration option if one needs some classes not present in any files.
